# Typescript Generic Specialization

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm looking for something akin to specialization in Typescript generics, where implementations can be disjoint based on type criteria.

A minimal example:

```
const someFunction = <A>() => { return 0; }

// something like this
<A extends String>someFunction = (a: A) => { return 1; }
<A extends Number>someFunction = (a: A) => { return 2; }
.
.
.

console.log(someFunction(false)); // prints 0
console.log(someFunction('string')); // prints 1
console.log(someFunction(42)); // prints 2
```

This is the "jist" of what I'd like. Is this possible in Typescript?

Comment: While it would be possible to modify TypeScript to support this, it would violate [Design Non-Goal #5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) about emitting different JavaScript code depending on the results of the type system.

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about does not exist in Typescript. The closest to this would be a [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html). Based on your example it would look something like this:

```
function someFunction(a: boolean): 0
function someFunction(a: string): 1
function someFunction(a: number): 2
function someFunction(a: any) {
  if(typeof a === 'boolean') {
    return 0
  } else if (typeof a === 'string') {
    return 1
  } else if (typeof a === 'number') {
    return 2
  }
}
```

This example works with primitives and `typeof` but would work the same with complex values and other [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) including User-Defined Type Guards.

Comment: Yes and no. They share a function body, which is one thing I'm trying to avoid. Furthermore, `typeof` will only succeed in this method for primitives. Interfaces will all return `object`, so there isn't a simple way to do coding conditions on types unless they're guaranteed to be primitives. Lastly, typescript would have enough information to choose the functions at compile-time. This approach does so at runtime.

Comment: I don't think what you're talking about can be done in typescript. My example uses `typeof` because your example uses primitive values. You could just as easily use  user-defined type guards instead.

Comment: Updated post to match.

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa Type guards are what you're looking for since they are used during statical analysis to deduce the type of a given object.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an interesting feature called "type guards" in TypeScript:

```js
export function isString(value: any): value is string {
  return typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String;
}
```

With a function defined like this you can make expressions like:

```js
function validate(value: string|string[]): string|void {
  if (isString(value) && value.replace(/\s+|\s+/g, '') === '')) {
    return this.msg;
  }
}
```

Notice, that method `replace` doesn't exist in type `string[]`, so the compiler would raise an error if I had just used function overload instead.